# sheetjs excel to json - adding extra <tr> for each row

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I couldn't find anything on SO that matched my question. I'm using Sheetjs plugin to convert an excel sheet into json, and displaying it using jquery in the browser. I'm able to do the conversion and display, but I have a use-case where I need to validate each of the json rows with data returned from a jquery ajax 'GET' call.

I'm able to perform that validation as well. Once each excel json row is validated against the values from the ajax response, based on a set of rules, the excel json row is marked either a success row or an error row. For success rows, I perform no action. For error row, I need to add an additional key/value pair in the json element, denoting the error type, and the error description. Further, this error row, when displayed in the browser needs to have a css style with a color:red for red text, to indicate an error.

I haven't seen anything in Sheetjs documentation that might allow me to do this, but I'm pretty sure it can be done. In the code below, I have to modify the helper function called BindTable() in order to add the css style to set the text color to red IF it is an error row. I also have to somehow add a  for each of the error rows in order to display the error type and error description.

In the below code, I need to be able to display the invalidRequests JSON object with the css style applied to display the text in red color. Or, if there is a way to directly manipulate the exceljson JSON object to somehow append the key/value pairs of MSG1/message to each of the error rows, that would be even better. I realize that due to the nature of this question, I can't create a jsfiddle, but any ideas/suggestion/comments would be extremely helpful, even if it doesn't provide the complete solution.

Expected format:

author1     JOHN DOE        USA           N.AMERICA
ERROR: THIS AUTHOR NAME ALREADY EXISTS IN THE SYSTEM!

This is the code that I currently have:

---

```
//Excel Reader 
function ExcelToTable(event) { 
    event.preventDefault();

    var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9\s_\\.\-:])+(.xlsx|.xls)$/;  
    /*Checks whether the file is a valid excel file*/  
    if (regex.test($("#excelfile").val().toLowerCase())) {  
        var xlsxflag = false; /*Flag for checking whether excel is .xls 
format or .xlsx format*/  
        if ($("#excelfile").val().toLowerCase().indexOf(".xlsx") > 0) {  
            xlsxflag = true;  
        }  
        /*Checks whether the browser supports HTML5*/  
        if (typeof (FileReader) != "undefined") {  
            var reader = new FileReader();  
            reader.onload = function (e) {  
                var data = e.target.result;  

                //pre-process data
                var binary = "";
                var bytes = new Uint8Array(data);
                var length = bytes.byteLength;
                for(var i=0;i<length;i++){
                    binary += String.fromCharCode(bytes[i]);
                }
                // /pre-process data

                /*Converts the excel data in to object*/  
                if (xlsxflag) {  
                   // var workbook = XLSX.read(data, { type: 'binary' });  

                   var workbook = XLSX.read(binary, {type: 'binary'});
                }  
                else {  
                    var workbook = XLS.read(binary, { type: 'binary' });  
                }  
                /*Gets all the sheetnames of excel in to a variable*/  
                var sheet_name_list = workbook.SheetNames; 

              //  console.log('Sheet name list : ' + sheet_name_list);

                var cnt = 0; /*This is used for restricting the script to 
consider only first sheet of excel*/  
              //  sheet_name_list.forEach(function (y) { /*Iterate through 
all sheets*/  
                    /*Convert the cell value to Json*/  

                    if (xlsxflag) {                      
                        exceljson = 
XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets['CUSTOM_EXCEL_TAB'],{defval: 
"NULL"});
                        var emptyAuthorCells =[];
                        var invalidCountryCells = [];

                       Object.keys(exceljson).forEach(function(value, key) {
                           if(exceljson[key].AUTHOR == 'ADD'){
                           }
                            else if(exceljson[key].AUTHOR == 'NULL'){
                                    emptyAuthorCells.push({'MARKET': 
exceljson[key].MARKET, 'REGION':exceljson[key].REGION, 
'PARTNER':exceljson[key].PARTNER, 'AUTHOR': exceljson[key].AUTHOR }); 
                            }
                            //check effective end date
                           if((exceljson[key].DATE_ENDING != '') || 
(exceljson[key].DATE_ENDING <= getTodayDate())){
                                invalidCountryCells.push({
                                    'MARKET': exceljson[key].MARKET, 
'REGION':exceljson[key].REGION, 'PARTNER':exceljson[key].PARTNER, 'AUTHOR': 
exceljson[key].AUTHOR
                                });
                            }                       
                      });
                      var emptyActionCellsMessage = "There were " + 
emptyAuthorCells.length + " rows with Author=Null <br />";
                      var completedActionCellsMessage = " Success! There 
were " + emptyAuthorCells.length + " rows with authro=Null <br />";
                      var invalidDateMsg = "There are missing or incorrect 
    date values.";
                      var validCompareDataMessage = "Success! All data has been successfully validated!";
                      var invalidCompareDataMessage = "Validation Failed! 
Data does not match Rules.";
                    }  
                    else {  
                        var exceljson = 
 XLS.utils.sheet_to_row_object_array(workbook.Sheets[y]);  
                    }  

                    var conflictRows = [];
                    var returnedRows = [];
                    var errorReturnedRows = [];

                    if(emptyAuthorCells.length == 0){
                        var uniqueAuthor = $.unique(exceljson.map(function 
(d){
                            return d.MARKET;

                        }));
                        var doAllValidations = function(){
                            var ajaxList = [];
                            var ajxIndex = 1;
                           $.each(uniqueAuthor, function (index, value){
                            var jqResponse = 
                            $.ajax({
                                type: "get",
                                url: "authorlist.cfm?method=getlist&name=" + 
value,
                                dataType: "json"
                            });
                            ajaxList.push(jqResponse);
                            jqResponse.then(
                                function( apiResponse ){
                                    $.each (apiResponse, function (cc) {

if(apiResponse[cc].hasOwnProperty('SUCCESS')){
                                                errorReturnedRows.push({
                                                    'success': 
apiResponse[cc].SUCCESS,
                                                    'message': 
apiResponse[cc].MESSAGE,
                                                    'country_code' : value
                                                });                               
                                        }
                                        else{


returnedRows.push(apiResponse[cc]);
                                        }
                                    // }

                                  //  }
                                });
                                }

                            );
                    });
                    return ajaxList;
                };
                        // /LOOP OVER country_code
                    }
                  var invalidRequests = [];
                  var validRequests = [];

                  $(function() {
                    var ajaxCalls = doAllValidations();
                    //begin apply
                    $.when.apply($, ajaxCalls).done(function(){
                        //console.log(ajaxList);
                        $('#hidReturnedRows').val();

$('#hidReturnedRows').val(JSON.stringify(returnedRows));
                        if (exceljson.length > 0 && cnt == 0) { 
                            if((emptyAuthorCells.length != 0) || 
 (errorReturnedRows.length!=0) ) {
                                //data is invalid
                                console.log("data is invalid");
                                $('#displayErrors tr 
 td.previewSuccessClass').html("");
                                $('#displayErrors tr 
 td.previewErrorsClass').html(emptyActionCellsMessage);
                                $('#export-file').addClass('hidebtn');
                            }
                            else{
                                //outer loop  
                                    var found = false;
                                    var book_found = false;
                                    var response_validation_errors = [];
                                    var message = "The author's zone is 
 incorrect";
                                    var message2 = "This book already 
 exists";
                                        $.each(exceljson, function(x, ej){
                                           // console.log("inside outer 
     loop");
                                            found = false;
                                            $.each(returnedRows, function(y, 
     rr){

                                            //compare inner row with outer 
row to make sure they're the same
                                            if(rr.AUTHOR_ID == ej.ID && 
rr.AUTHOR_NAME == ej.NAME)
                                            {
                                                if((rr.AUTHOR == 
 ej.NATIVE_AUTHOR) && (rr.BOOK_QUALITY == ej.AUTHOR_ZONE)){
                                               // console.log("found!");
                                                    found = true;
                                                }
                                            }
                                            });
                                            if(found){
                                                invalidRequests.push({
                                                    "AUTHOR": ej.NAME,
                                                    "AUTHOR_ZONE": 
 ej.AUTHOR_ZONE,
                                                    "COUNTRY": ej.COUNTRY
                                                });
                                            }
                                            else{
                                                validRequests.push(ej);
                                            }
                                        });
                                        // /outer loop                                   
                            }
                            BindTable(exceljson, '#exceltable');  
                            cnt++;  
                        } 

                    })();
                    //end apply
                });  
            };  
            if (xlsxflag) {/*If excel file is .xlsx extension than creates a 
Array Buffer from excel*/  
                reader.readAsArrayBuffer($("#excelfile")[0].files[0]);  
            }  
            else {  
                reader.readAsBinaryString($("#excelfile")[0].files[0]);  
            }  
        }  
        else {  
            alert("Sorry! Your browser does not support HTML5!");  
        }  
    }  
    else {  
        alert("Please upload a valid Excel file!");  
    }  
} 

//Helper funcs
function BindTable(jsondata, tableid, invalidreqs) {/*Function used to convert the JSON 
array to Html Table*/  
   var columns = BindTableHeader(jsondata, tableid); /*Gets all the column 
   headings of Excel*/

   //ADDED .map() & .find() INSTEAD OF NESTED LOOPS 
    jsondata.map(a => {

    // SEARCH FOR AN ELEMENT IN invalidreqs THAT MATCH THE 
    // CRITERIA TESTED FOR IN THE FUNCTION
  if (invalidreqs.find(b => {
     return a.AUTHOR == b.AUTHOR && a.BOOKNAME == b.BOOKNAME && a.COUNTRY == 
    b.COUNTRY;
    })) {
     a.MSG = "THIS ROW ALREADY EXISTS";
   }
```

});

console.log (jsondata);

```
        //THE BELOW CODE NEEDS TO BE CHANGED
        var row$ = $('<tr/>');  
        for (var colIndex = 0; colIndex < columns.length; colIndex++) {  
            var cellValue = jsondata[i][columns[colIndex]];  
            row$.append($('<td/>').html(cellValue));  
        } 
        //console.log("before table append"); 
        $(tableid).append(row$);  
        if( has_error ){
            row$.addClass( 'response-errors' );//add class to make text red
            var error_row = $('<tr/>');
            var error_cell = $('<td/>');
            error_cell.attr('colspan', column.length); //set cols to span lenght of row
            error_cell.html("SET ERROR MESSAGE TO DISPLAY BASED ON invalidreq object");
            error_row.append( error_cell );
            $( tableid ).append( error_row );
        }
    } 
    // /Outer loop 
}  
function BindTableHeader(jsondata, tableid) {/*Function used to get all 
column names from JSON and bind the html table header*/  
    var columnSet = [];  
    var headerTr$ = $('<tr/>');  
    for (var i = 0; i < jsondata.length; i++) {  
        var rowHash = jsondata[i];  
        for (var key in rowHash) {  
            if (rowHash.hasOwnProperty(key)) {  
                if ($.inArray(key, columnSet) == -1) {/*Adding each unique 
column names to a variable array*/  
                    columnSet.push(key);  
                   // console.log(key);
                    headerTr$.append($('<th/>').html(key));  
                }  
            }  
        }  
    }  
    $(tableid).append(headerTr$);  
    return columnSet;  
  }
```

Comment: So by 'adding extra <tr>' you mean it should add a row below the actual data containing the error descriptions? If so, how do you specify in which column the error should appear?

Comment: @Manuel Otto - That's correct - so if the data row has an error, the error message should be in a <tr> right below that, but within the <tr> of the data row - so as to be able to display to the user that that specific error belongs to the data row that it is contained in. I guess what it essentially means is that the data row and its associated error message should be displayed as being all in one row.The display would look something like this:

Comment: AUTHOR NAME COUNTRY REGION *************************************************** author1 john doe usa namerica error: John Doe author name already exists! ------------------------------------------------------------ author2 jane doe canada namerica ------------------------------------------------------------ author3 wu xishang china europe error: Country & region do not match! ----------------------------------------------------- Notice that row1 and row3 have errors, but row2 does not. But the user can see each row separately –

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so what you want to do is:

1) Assign the row index to the `invalidRequests` object, on line 191 like this:

```
invalidRequests.push({
    "AUTHOR": ej.NAME,
    "AUTHOR_ZONE": ej.AUTHOR_ZONE,
    "COUNTRY": ej.COUNTRY,
    "index": x,
    "MSG1": "Put the error message here"
});
```

Now it is very easy to determine which row has an error.

Since the `invalidRequests` is a private object of the `ExcelTable` function, you will need to

2) pass it on to the `BindTable` function like this:

```
BindTable(exceljson, '#exceltable', invalidRequests);
```

3) modify the `BindTable` function to check for invalidRequests and handle them:

```
function BindTable(jsondata, tableid, invalidreqs) {
    var columns = BindTableHeader(jsondata, tableid);
    for (var i = 0; i < jsondata.length; i++) {  
        //look for rows with error
        var has_error = false
        var invalidreq
        for(var u=0;u<invalidreqs.length;u++){
            if(i==invalidreqs[u].index){
                //found invalid request belonging to current row, set flag
                has_error = true
                invalidreq = invalidreqs[u] // and store the current invalidrequest infos on temp obj
                //break - not really needed
            }
        }

        var row$ = $('<tr/>');  
        for (var colIndex = 0; colIndex < columns.length; colIndex++) {  
            var cellValue = jsondata[i][columns[colIndex]];  
            row$.append($('<td/>').html(cellValue));  
        } 
        $(tableid).append(row$); 

        if(has_error){
            row$.addClass('error') // add css class which will make the text red or whatever

            var error_row = $('<tr/>') // create error row
            var error_cell = $('<td/>')
            error_cell.attr('colspan',columns.length) // set column to span over all columns of table
            error_cell.html(invalidreq.MSG1)
            error_row.append(error_cell)
            $(tableid).append(error_row); 
        } 
    }  
}
```

Please note it is not clear, nor specified in your code, in which column the error should appear. Try to implement that yourself by pushing that info into the invalidRequests object and reading it out on BindTable.

Comment: I guess I should've made that clearer - so the error should span all the columns in the row - I tried posting a sample of the expected table but the formatting was messed up in the comments section. Let me try again:
author1    jane doe     usa       north america
ERROR:  THIS AUTHOR NAME ALREADY EXISTS!

Comment: Darn it - the format got messed up again! I've edited the original question code section, and added the expected format.

Comment: Oh, great, because thats how I implemented it right now :)

Comment: Oh yes, I see the colspan, perfect! Let me give this a whirl. Will report back.

Comment: Manuel - does the "index" : x have to be a dynamic value? In other words does x have to be set dynamically as a counter or something? Or does it stay constant as x in all the error rows? I guess I'm confused on the reason for having that additional key/value pair.

Comment: the "index" is used to determine which error belongs to which row, it has to be dynamic. It's origin is from when you iterate over exceljson `$.each(exceljson, function(x, ej){...` where x is the # of the current row. Does my code actually work? had no chance to test it.

Comment: I tried using the code that you provided - but the 'break' throws an error, so I replaced it with return, which is the javascript way I guess. But there seems to be a problem w/ the inner for loop to check is has_error is true. I think if statement there comparing i==invalidreqs[u].index isn't working. I'm still making changes to see if I can make it work. Will post my results in a couple of hours.

Comment: hmm, the break cant possibly throw an error. If you replace it with return, it will stop the whole BindTable process, leaving you with an incomplete table. The error has to be somewhere else...

Comment: I get a jquery.deferred error with break, but using a return fixes that. The problem now is to get the error message key/value pair appended to the jsondata object - so when the check is done in the if statement inside the inner loop in BindTable, once the row in jsondata matches the row in invalidrequests, the message key/value has to be appended to that row of the jsondata JSON object. I can post that the code that I have now and the expected result in the original post's code if you'd like?

Comment: I added the changed code inside the code section of my original question. I inserted comments in caps to notate what needs to happen, once the row from invalidreqs[u] is matched up with the jsondata[i] row.

Comment: Ok, I edited my post. I saw in your code that you didn't define the index when you pushed to invalidRequests. That's probably why it didnt work. You also need to specify the `MSG1` there. Remove the `return false` as it will break your table.

Comment: I made the changes, but for some reason no rows are being displayed after BindTable. Trying to debug now.

Comment: OK I changed the nested for loops and instead used .map() and .find() functions and they work. I made the updates in the code section of my original question. So now the jsondata object gets added with a key/value pair - "MSG": "THIS ROW ALREADY EXISTS" - if there is a match between jsondata & invalidreqs. But now I'm getting an error from the BindTableHeader() function since the jsondata object that is passed to it doesn't have the newly created key/val pair of "MSG":"This row already..." in it. BindTableHeader() is the function that creates all the column headers but I don't need a

Comment: separate column for "MSG" but instead, it needs to be in a <tr/> that has a colspan of columns.length. How do I accomplish this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157931/discussion-between-manuel-otto-and-roger-dodger).